# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'

Tags: swift

I have created one class name Users as below

```
public class Users: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
}
```

and other class create array of user class

```
var regUser = [Users]()
```

and

```
func fetchUser(){
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: {(DataSnapshot) in
        if let dictionary = DataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let user = Users()

            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            self.users.append(user)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            print(user.email)
        }   
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

The following error occurs:

> "Users 0x60400028fdc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Key-value coding depends on Objective-C, and under Swift 4 and the new Objective-C inference rules, your `name` and `email` properties will not be available.

You can mark individual properties as `@objc`:

```
@objc var name: String?
```

or you can say that everything in the class is available:

```
@objcMembers
public class Users: NSObject {
```

Comment: Thanks for Help me its work properly.

Comment: Perfect answer...